# In mercurial how to pull?

Tags: mercurial

I have cloned a branch name **abc** from bitbucket into my local by following command:

```
$ hg clone -b abc https://bitbucket.org/asda/da/
```

Next i have have created a branch name **xyz** from **abc** branch and it is my working branch .

```
$ hg branch <branch name>
```

Now my question was can i pull changes from remote **abc** to local **xyz** directly by following command:

```
$ hg pull -b abc
$ hg update
```

I always checkout to **abc** branch and then pull changes. When i pull changes nothing changes very confused regarding this.After pull it shows total number of files changed .But not able to see changes.

Another question is that if i pull changes on branch **abc** and when i checkout **xyz** branch does all the changes get updated in **xyz** branch automatically?

Please help me out.

Comment: pull then merge

Comment: Means pull abc and then merge abc into xyz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture of the branches. When you pull new changesets, they are *always* added to the same branch, and in the same sequence, that they occupied in the upstream repository. In other words when you pull from `abc` you extend `abc`. You don't need to switch to `abc` before you pull, and you don't need to update afterwards.

```
a--a--a--a--a1--a2
          \
           x--x--x
```

(`a` = branch `abc`; `a1,a2` = new changesets on `abc`; `x` = branch `xyz`)

The new changesets you pulled make no difference to the tip of branch `xyz`. To benefit from them in your branch, use the command `merge`.

```
hg update xyz
hg merge a2
hg commit
```

Then you'll be at point X', the new tip of `xyz`.

```
a--a--a--a---a1---a2
          \        \
           x--x--x--X'
```

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are the new changesets you just pulled. You can also use the branch name to merge: it is understood to mean the last revision on that branch, so `hg merge abc` will be the same as `hg merge a2`.

Comment: hello @alexis pulled changes locally **abc** branch from remote bitbucket and checked out **xyz** and merged **abc** by `hg merge abc` solved the conflicts and continued working on that branch.Now when i run `hg add .` and then run `hg commit -m ` it gives me error abort:uncommites merged changes. Is it because of i didnt commit or update the branch after merging? Solution Really stuck here and i also dont want to loose the changes i made on **xyz** branch.

Comment: `abort: outstanding uncommitted changes` this is the error i get after commit.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a mistake, you should have followed my recipe to the end. Make a full backup copy, before you try anything more, that way you won't lose the changes. I recommend cloning your local repo to a sister directory, then you can hand-copy selected files and get things working step by step. But research it first. This is a new question you've waded into, and there's plenty here on SO about recovering from merges gone awry.

Comment: I have just started using hg ,sometimes I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Understandable. There's no obvious reason `merge` doesn't do its own commit. Read the mercurial book, it's great. (And don't skip steps when you get a 3 step answer...)